Косноязыкий или косноязычный? В чем отличие?
В словарях указано, что это синонимы, но так ли это?  Слова могут отличаться по семантическим оттенкам и стилю речи, а также по  области употребления. К тому же само слово косноязычный  имеет разные значения (3 варианта).
Продолжение темы 2014 года  Какого человека называют косноязыким или косноязычным?
Миниатюра «Косноязыкий или косноязычный»?"
— Вы меня в своей статье назвали косноязычным!
— Так оно и есть.
— Да у меня дикция получше вашей!
— Я сказал косноязычный, а не косноязыкий.
— Так это одно и то же, в словаре же написано! 
  Косноязыкий, -ая, -ое; = Косноязычный.   И вот 
  еще:* Был слеп Гомер, и глух Бетховен, И Демосфен 
  косноязык (Кедрин).
— Демосфен косноязыким был в детстве,  а потом много 
  работал над своей  речью. Камешки себе в рот 
  набирал. Но при этом он был искусным сочинителем. 
  Я об этом…
— Так вам мой стиль не нравится?
— Не нравится. Вы пишете как телеграфист.
— Я пишу коротко и ясно. Вам, может,  и Чехов не по душе?..
И т.д.

Юрий Бондарев. Берег (1975)
— Артельные Сократы вы, домашние правдолюбцы, жуете и пережевываете оскоминные аксиомы за рюмкой водки? Вам нравится косноязычный телеграфный стиль? Я не телеграфист!
Дмитрий Кедрин — Был слеп Гомер, и глух Бетховен, 1944 год
Был слеп Гомер, и глух Бетховен,
И Демосфен косноязык.
Но кто поднялся с ними вровень,
Кто к музам, как они, привык?
Так что ж педант, насупясь, пишет,
Что творчество лишь тем дано,
Кто остро видит, тонко слышит,
Умеет говорить красно?
Иль им, не озаренным духом,
Один закон всего знаком —
Творить со слишком тонким слухом
И слишком длинным языком?..

КОСНОЯЗЫЧИЕ, -я; ср. 1. Неспособность чётко произносить некоторые звуки; невнятное, неясное произношение. Страдать косноязычием. 2. Неумение владеть речью, говорить свободно, не спотыкаясь. К. выступающего утомляло.
КОСНОЯЗЫЧНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -чен, -чна, -чно. 1. Страдающий косноязычием. Он очень косноязычен. 2. Невнятный, неясный (о речи). 3. Изложенный, написанный невыразительно, с языковыми ошибками. Некоторые сочинения были примитивны и косноязычны. Косноязычно, нареч. Говорить к.
КОСНОЯЗЫКИЙ
Большой толковый словарь русского языка
КОСНОЯЗЫКИЙ, -ая, -ое; -зык, -а, -о. =Косноязычный. * Был слеп Гомер, и глух Бетховен, И Демосфен косноязык (Кедрин). Косноязыко, нареч.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

О слове косноязыкий

Неужели Д. Кедрин изобрел это слово, чтобы зарифмовать стихотворение, а потом оно с его подачи попало в толковые словари? Может быть, и так, разве мало примеров, когда писатели придумывали слова?

Но в любом случае это правильное слово, образованное по грамматическим законам русского языка. Оно отнюдь не единственное, ведь существуют слова многоязыкий, разноязыкий, безъязыкий. Правда, существуют они не так давно, но чужими не кажутся.
Карта слов: Список слов, оканчивающихся на «-языкий»: разноязыкий, безъязыкий, многоязыкий. Интересно, что все примеры из современной литературы.
Разношёрстная, разноязыкая толпа шумно выплёскивается на перрон.
Алёна Даль, Хождение по Млечному Пути, 2019
Вокруг теснилась многоязыкая толпа, от криков и шума в ушах стоял непрерывный звон.
Олег Яковлев, Ромейская история, 2023
Но где-то вдалеке, за визгом безъязыких птиц, нарастал глухой рёв. Джон Парк Дэвис, Сердце Потока, 2018
БЕЗЪЯЗЫКИЙ, -ая, -ое; -зык, -а, -о. 1. Не имеющий языка, лишившийся его. 2. Разг. Не владеющий или плохо владеющий речью, языком (обычно иностранным). // Не умеющий доходчиво объяснять или хорошо рассказывать. [] в зн. сущ. * Горе в чужой земле безъязыкому (Посл.). Безъязыкость, -и; ж.

По такой же модели образованы слова многоликий, разноликий, которые очень популярны в современной литературе. Кстати, многоликий отнюдь не новое слово:

Мы все вместе живем, и как бы одна душа томится во всем многоликом человечестве. Мир весь во мне. Но страшно, что он таков, каков он есть, и как только его поймешь, так и увидишь, что он не должен быть, потому что он лежит в пороке и во зле. Надо обречь его на казнь, и себя с ним.
Сологуб Ф. К., Красота, 1899

Так что же это за модель, как образуется слово? Сравним слова: могоязычный и многоязыкий.

Для этого он держал при себе несколько дальних родственниц: свою сестру, больную и сварливую; двух сестер жены своей, тоже злых и многоязычных; потом свою старую тетку, у которой по какому-то случаю было сломано одно ребро.
Достоевский Ф. М., Скверный анекдот, 1862
Много языков: многоязычный, суффикс Н; многоязыкий, нулевой суффикс. Вот и вся разница в словообразовании. Правда, слова многоязычный нет в словаре.

Косноязычный — литературное слово с основным значением, а косноязыкий — разговорный вариант? Но стилевой пометки нет, да и  обе модели равноправные, используются в языке. Стиль разный, а СЕМАНТИКА? Мне думается, что тоже разная. А вот какая — об этом вопрос.

Причем он касается и остальных парных вариантов, например: разноязычный и разноязыкий. Большой толковый словарь русского языка.РАЗНОЯЗЫКИЙ, -ая, -ое; -зык, -а, -о. =Разноязычный.
ВЫВОД по комментариям. К единому мнению прийти не удалось, но моя точка зрения такая.
Безъязыкий — это совсем без языка или не умеющий им владеть. Нулевой суффикс прилагательного. Безъязычный — не умеющий владеть мыслью и словом. Суффикс Н относительного прилагательного, то есть значение приближено к речи, но удалено от материальности языка // Нет языка или другие проблемы с речевым аппаратом? Тогда остается возможность записать текст.
Аналогичное соответствие для пары косноязыкий (с дефектами речи) и косноязычный (не умеющий красиво и правильно говорить или писать). Слова считаются синонимами, но при противопоставлении значение именно такое. Также косноязыкий ближе к разговорной речи.

Sharon: «Неужели Д. Кедрин изобрел это слово?..» ===  Конечно нет. Слово косноязыкий можно встретить у писателей, живших и за сто лет до Кедрина…

Вам приходилось  встречать?  Кстати, у моем ответе вопрос риторический. Есть такой прием при построении речи.  Значение следующее:  я это допускаю в силу того, что это не так важно.
